# Написать движок игры на java

Tags: java, аудио, движок, физика, визуализация

Допустим захотел я написать движок для игр, зная только Java.
Как это возможно реализовать?

- Нужно написать отображение картинки ("звуковоиспроведение" / физику).

Реализация:
На ум приходит только создание библиотеки основанной на аплете, или JavaFX, или JavaEE (в последнем случае логика и отображение получаются сильно (слишком) взаимосвязаны).

---

Возможно ли это сделать на чистом JavaSE?

Comment: Учитывая что на VBA была написанная сетевая MMORPG, я с уверенностью скажу что на java написать полноценный движок более чем возможно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разумеется можно, Майнкрафт подтвердит. См. этот [список](https://github.com/Vedenin/useful-java-links#5-game-development), берите нужный фреймворк и делайте игры. Либо берете фреймворк с открытым кодом и смотрите как все там реализовано.

**P.S.** Проблема может быть с производительностью, если вы планируете сложную графику, все-таки С/С++/Rast и т.п. быстрее работают как числодробилки.

Comment: Спасибо.Я так понимаю, эту фреймворки и есть сами движки. Вопрос в том чтобы написать сам движок.

Comment: Ну так они open-source, можно открыть их код и посмотреть как они сделаны и даже скопировать частично или полностью этот код. А в чем необходимость написать движок именно самому, если найдется бесплатный open-source движок со всеми нужными фичами?

Comment: Интересна реализация и возможно ли это написать не используя С++/С сохранив максимальную производительность.

Comment: Максимальную производительность - сразу нет, Java как числодробилка не сможет сравниться с С/С++, просто потому что С/С++ может не делать проверок на выход из цикла или корректность указателей. Можно достичь производительность не сильно хуже скорости С/С++ (50%/70%/90% от скорости С), но достичь скорости С в числоробилках (не считая редких случаев) тоже самое что достичь скорости света в вакумме.